# R: group dates that are next to each other

Tags: r

I have a sequence of dates (years) that is irregular.

Specifically, year 2004 is followed by 2005, 2006 is missing, 2007 is present, followed by 2008, then sequence is missing years until 2014.

```
# data input
df_in <- 
  data.frame(seq = c(2004L, 2005L, 2007L, 2008L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L))

# desired result
df_out <- 
  data.frame(df_in, grp = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L))

   seq grp
1 2004   1
2 2005   1
3 2007   2
4 2008   2
5 2014   3
6 2015   3
7 2016   3
```

I would like to find a way to generate groups of years that are next to each other. So, group 1 would contain years 2004 and 2005, group 2 years 2007 and 2008, and group 3 years from 2014 to 2016.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df_in$group = 1 + c(0, cumsum(ifelse(diff(df_in$seq) > 1, 1, 0)))
```

The idea here is that `diff` calculates the lagged difference. When it's more than 1, we add one to the group. `cumsum` calculates the cumulative sum of those times we've encountered a gap, aka a new group. The `c(0,` is there because the output of `diff` is one shorter than our data, and we need a value for the first element. Finally, the `1 +` is just for optics, so the first group is 1 instead of 0.

```
> df_in$group 
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cumsum(c(1, diff(df_in$seq)) != 1) + 1
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. But I'd be great if someone else has a more elegant solution:

```
df_in <- data.frame(seq = c(2004L, 2005L, 2007L, 2008L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L))
```

Define maximal distance between elements **within** a group:

```
max_range_within_group <- 1
```

Calculate existing distances:

```
diffs <- df_in$seq[-1] - df_in$seq[-length(df_in$seq)]
```

Iterate trough distances and check if they are within 'allowed' distance or increase grp by 1:

```
grp <- 1
for (diff in diffs) {
  nextGrp <- if (diff <= max_range_within_group) {
    grp[length(grp)]
  } else {
    grp[length(grp)] + 1
  }
  grp <- c(grp, nextGrp)
}
```

Bind `grp` to data.frame:

```
df_in$grp <- grp
```

This returns:

```
   seq grp
1 2004   1
2 2005   1
3 2007   2
4 2008   2
5 2014   3
6 2015   3
7 2016   3
```